# SQLiteException attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to add an update method to update user information. 
Here is my update method:

```
//updating sqlite database with the group name
    public void updateUserGroup(String groupName) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_GROUP, groupName);
        HashMap<String, String> user = getUserDetails();
        String userID = user.get("uid");

        System.out.println("User id is: " + userID);
        db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, values, SQLiteHandler.KEY_UID + "=\"" + userID + "\"", null);
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/cindyliu96.test/databases/android_api
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1522)
```

Comment: Please provide us the full error message you are getting. You can do this by editing the current question.

Comment: Okay added the error!

Comment: Are you creating multiple instances of your subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

what about open your db connection, as it

```
db.open();
```

and when you finish your transaction or query

```
db.close();
```